# elisp: capturing variable from inner function

Tags: elisp

My lovely function:

```
(defun f (x)
  (lambda (y) (+ x y)))
```

Then, I expect this:

```
(funcall (f 2) 2)
```

To return 4. But alas, I got this instead:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable x)
```

So how can I capture variable from inner function?

Comment: As of Emacs 24, there is another workaround for the dynamic-scoping "bug": you can put `;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-` at the top of the file to enable lexical scoping. If you do this, the above code runs as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've been bitten by elisp's dynamic scoping. The `x` in the lambda refers to the variable `x` that is in scope when the lambda is called (and since in this case there is no `x` in scope when you call it, you get an error), not to the `x` which is in scope when you create the lambda.

Some ways of simulating lexical closures in elisp are explained on [this page on the EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FakeClosures).