# Higher-order functions in Elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, higher-order-functions, dynamic-binding

I created a function that returns a function in Elisp:

```
(defun singleton-set (elem)
  (defun f (n) (= n elem))
  f)
```

I try to run this in IELM, and it fails:

```
ELISP> (singleton-set 5)
*** Eval error ***  Symbol's value as variable is void: f
ELISP> ((singleton-set 5) 5)
*** Eval error ***  Invalid function: (singleton-set 5)
```

Due to [What is the difference between Lisp-1 and Lisp-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/596361) i changed the code to

```
(defun singleton-set (elem)
  (defun f (n) (= n elem))
  #'f)
```

And invocation to `(funcall (singleton-set 5) 5)`, but now the error is

`*** Eval error ***  Symbol's value as variable is void: elem`

I understand from [elisp: capturing variable from inner function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5020009/596361) that this is due to dynamic binding of Emacs Lisp.

How to make functions returning functions possible in Emacs Lisp? What is the reason this mechanism is different from other languages like Python, Scala or Clojure?

Related questions:

- [elisp functions as parameters and as return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661490/596361)
- [Elisp interactive function name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5372055/596361)
- [How to Create a Temporary Function in Emacs Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2657326/596361)
- [In elisp, how do I put a function in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9942675/596361)

Comment: possible duplicate of [elisp functions as parameters and as return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661490/elisp-functions-as-parameters-and-as-return-value)

Comment: You don't want to use `defun` inside of `singleton-set`.  Use something like `(defun singleton-set (elem) #'(lambda ...))` instead, and look at @geocar's pointers below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the `NEWS` for Emacs 24:

> Lisp changes in Emacs 24.1
>
> - Code can now use lexical scoping by default instead of dynamic scoping.
>     The `lexical-binding` variable enables lexical scoping for local
>     variables.  It is typically set via a file-local variable in the first
>     line of the file, in which case it applies to all the code in that
>     file.

So, in Emacs 24:

```
(setq lexical-binding t)
(defun singleton-set (elem) (lambda (n) (= n elem)))
(mapcar (singleton-set 1) '(0 1 2 3))
    ===> (nil t nil nil)
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to use lexical binding to me -- maybe I'm missing something. I don't see any kind of closure in the code.

Comment: @CharlieFlowers: You're missing something. (Try it with `lexical-binding` turned on and off and you'll see.) `elem` needs to be lexically bound if the `lambda` is to be callable outside of the call to `singleton-set`.

Answer (score 6):

> How to make functions returning functions possible in Emacs Lisp?

Using [fake closures](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FakeClosures), and `lexical-let`.

> What is the reason this mechanism is different from other languages like Python, Scala or Clojure?

Richard Stallman [answered this question](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-paper.html#SEC17) in a paper he wrote a while ago.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun singleton-set (elem)
  `(lambda (n) (= n ,elem))
```

See: [elisp functions as parameters and as return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661490/596361)